# Tracking down a PHP performance issue

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which runs fine on a Raspberry Pi PHP 5.4.4, but when I run the same script on a Cubieboard2 ( about twice the power of the Pi) PHP 5.4.6 I get a long delay. In both cases there is no caching of the PHP as far as I know. The problem seems to be with a file_get_contents request which is retrieving some xml from the web. Although if I enter the same information in a browser in the same system it comes back quickly enough.

There are no related entries in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Any ideas of how to track the problem down.

Thanks

Comment: wrap file_get_contents in microtime?

Comment: I should add that if I try a php script with just echo "test"; it runs just fine.

Comment: Somebody suggested adding microtime statements. I find that its definitely the file_get_contents statement that is taking 20-30 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if both systems have the same settings for ipv6. Some distributions have ipv6 enabled and tries that before ipv4.

Comment: CubieBoard 2 Did have IPv6 enabled where as Pi was only IPv4, but disabled IPv6, reboot, check with ifconfig and now just IPv4, but problem has not gone away.

Comment: How is the speed compared to the two devices if you get the file with wget?

Comment: wget does not seem to complete.
Both devices are slow and the Cubiboard2 is slightly faster than the Raspberry Pi

Comment: If I change the $url request from https://secure.worldcommunitygrid.org/stat/viewCompareMembers.do?userNames[0].value=KeithSloan&xml=true
To
https://198.20.8.246/stat/viewCompareMembers.do?userNames[0].value=KeithSloan&xml=true
It still takes a long tine for the $xml = file_get_contents($url);

Works just fine and quick on the Raspberry Pi

Comment: I have no SSL configured on the Raspberry Pi, so wonder if it is a problem with out going request on Cubieboard2 that does have SSL

Comment: Okay tried sudo a2dismod ssl
sudo a2dissite default-ssl
sudo service apache2 restart

Problem still exists

Comment: Strange that wget does not complete. Are you sure that php retrieves the file or that it is an timeout that finished it.

Comment: wget does complete, just when I try it from command line it spawns a new task and I did not pick up on that.

Comment: Have now tried to use curl rather than file_get_contents. curl_getinfo($ch); comes back with Array ( [url] => https://secure.worldcommunitygrid.org/stat/viewCompareMembers.do?userNames[0].value=KeithSloan&xml=true [content_type] => text/xml; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 409 [request_size] => 133 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 21.510284 [namelookup_time] => 20.007878 [connect_time] => 20.123805 [pretransfer_time] => 20.873649 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 4129 [speed_download] => 191 [speed_upload] => 0

Comment: [download_content_length] => 4129 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 21.51009 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 198.20.8.246 [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 192.168.1.4 [local_port] => 50097 [redirect_url] => )

Comment: Try adding this to your curl options:curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

Comment: Changed DNS server to 8.8.8.8 in /etc/resolv.conf but still have a problem, despite namelookup no longer being an issue.
[total_time] => 16.881535 [namelookup_time] => 0.171685 [connect_time] => 15.322066 [pretransfer_time] => 16.628485

Comment: Thanks Martin
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ); seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

Could be a reverse DNS lookup with a invalid resolve setup. 
Check if apache(or your webserver) has set reverse dns for logging.

Check 
https://serverfault.com/questions/100225/apache-httpd-wont-stop-doing-reverse-dns-requests-for-clients-ips 
or just google it

And check if you can `ping www.google.at` from a shell.

Comment: When I check /var/log/apache2/access.log then all accesses just have IP address rather than name so I don't think reverse-dns is on. HostNamesLookup is off in the config.
I can ping www.google.at just fine.